# ASP:Button CSS :after Selector (or :before)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

Does anyone know how to make it work?
It's weird cause when I'm testing only HTML & CSS - it's working well, but when I'm trying to add it to ASP:
.button - works well, but .button:after (or.button:before) - not working at all...

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" type="submit" runat="server" CssClass="login-button" Text="Login"></asp:Button>
```

---

```
.login-button:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 12px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 19px;
  background: url("../img/bg.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Kindly paste your code as well. It will be easily to drill down the issue

Comment: Just Added. If it's hard maybe just give me a hint where to start

Comment: you don't need to paste the whole code, just paste the relevant and be specific where you're facing the issue

Comment: For instance, when I use it like:
<button type="submit" class="login-button">Login</button>
works perfect,
but when I use it like I wrote in a beginning  nothing happening

Answer (score 0):

The `<asp:Button>` renders as `<input type="button"... />` in browser.

Either add `runat="server"` with `name="btnSubmit"` and `id="btnSubmit"` to `<button>` tag or create your own custom asp.net control:

```
<button type="submit" runat="server" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" class="login-button">Login</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<button type="submit" runat="server" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" class="login-button">
        Login</button>
```

instead of

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="login-button" Text="Login"/>
```

this is work for me in my Application

Comment: I'm also having the same issue. But I could not change asp button to normal html button as I am using on command click event. Can anyone suggest me an alternate solution for this.

Thanks in Advance